# How do I show a child window when a button is clicked in sketchflow?

Tags: sketchflow

How do I show a child window when a button is clicked in sketchflow ?

I know how to do this in C#/Java/C++, but not sure how to do it in sketchflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SketchFlow can use C#, so if you know how to do it there, you should be set.